# Non-type template arguments of Function by reference or default?

Tags: c++, c++17

Should I take nttp functions by reference or by "value" (implicit pointer)?

```c
template< auto fn >
struct c
{
    static constexpr auto functor = fn;
};
```

vs

```
template< auto & fn >
struct c
{
    static constexpr auto functor = fn;
    static constexpr auto && functor = fn; // maybe?
};
```

Or does it not matter? If it is compiler dependent, let the question be about MSVC

Usage:

```
c< GetLastError >::functor( );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a function to a template as a non type template argument. It will always refer to the same function, because it's actually the function's address. In this case, `auto` is fine.

Usually people use `auto` for their needs, but you may use a pointer or a reference to refer to global data (e.g., variables with file level scoping).

Comment: What about the concern of passing functions by direct address, i.e. `c< &GetLastError >`? Is this a factor to consider or does it not really matter since functions decay to their addresses anyway?

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: Will this affect inline-ability of the functions?

Comment: @lajoh90686 generally not.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that?